# Downloading/Running another persons React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I downloaded off Github a friends react app to see what some functions are doing and design. I've been trying to run the application but keep running into errors. I extracted the folder out of the Zip file and in the command line run `npm install` and then doing `npm start` the error I encounter is the following:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\package.json'
  npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. 
   npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RafayChaudhary\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02- 
03T19_49_57_690Z-debug.log
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PowerShell directory is pointing to the System dir for PowerShell i.e.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

You need to change this to the directory of your React app e.g.

```
cd C:\Path\To\React\App
npm i && npm start
```